# Aggregate boolean table with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table. All values are 0 or 1.

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

and I want this one

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |

This last table answers to the question how many rows have {raw} and {col} set to 1. For example, there are 2 rows where a = b = 1 in the first table, so cell(a,b) = 2.

I have a query that is not suitable for large tables. Is it possible to make it simpler?

```
SELECT
    'a' AS ' ',  
    SUM(a) AS a, 
    (SELECT SUM(b) FROM tab WHERE a = 1) AS b, 
    (SELECT SUM(c) FROM tab WHERE a = 1) AS c 
FROM 
    tab

UNION

SELECT
    'b', 
    (SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab WHERE b = 1),
    SUM(b), 
    (SELECT SUM(c) FROM tab WHERE b = 1) 
FROM
    tab

UNION

SELECT
    'c', 
    (SELECT SUM(a) FROM tab WHERE c = 1), 
    (SELECT SUM(b) FROM tab WHERE c = 1),
    SUM(c) 
FROM
    tab
```

Comment: You say you have a "boolean table" but there is no boolean in sql server. Often the bit datatype is used for a boolean but you can't use SUM for a bit. What is your actual datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that is easy to extend with more columns. Just add them where there are arrows in comments:

```
with t1 as (select *, row_number() over (order by a) as rn from t),
u(col, rn, val) as (
    select 'a', rn, a from t1 union all
    select 'b', rn, b from t1 union all
    select 'c', rn, c from t1 union all
    select 'd', rn, d from t1                           /* <-- */
), data as (
    select d1.col as Rx, d2.col as Cx,
        case when d1.val = 1 and d2.val = 1 then 1 else 0 end as v
    from u as d1 inner join u as d2 on d1.rn = d2.rn
)
select Rx as [ ], [a], [b], [c], [d]                    /* <-- */
from data as src
pivot (sum(v) for Cx in ([a], [b], [c], [d])) as pvt;   /* <-- */
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f8022109a8885d661e81f4a2792b8c4

Comment: I choose this solution because it is the most scalable and I will need more columns (for correlation studies) but Stu and forpas solutions are also very elegant

Comment: @Polux2 Thanks. I just cleaned this up a bit, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following using conditional aggregation instead of sub-queries, it's probably a little bit cleaner:

```
select 'a' [ ],
 Sum (case when a = a then a else 0 end) a,
 Sum (case when a = b then b else 0 end) b,
 Sum (case when a = c then c else 0 end) c
from t 
union all
select 'b' [ ],
 Sum (case when b = a then a else 0 end) a,
 Sum (case when b = b then b else 0 end) b,
 Sum (case when b = c then c else 0 end) c
from t 
union all
select 'c' [ ],
 Sum (case when c = a then a else 0 end) a,
 Sum (case when c = b then b else 0 end) b,
 Sum (case when c = c then c else 0 end) c
from t;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0dd9dd56a38c5da774a1bc9168a7c06)

Comment: Much shorter than my solution +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate only once in the table:

```
WITH 
  v AS (SELECT v FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) v(v)),
  s AS (
    SELECT SUM(a) a, SUM(b) b, SUM(c) c,
           SUM(a * b) ab, SUM(b * c) bc, SUM(c * a) ca
    FROM tab
  )  
SELECT v.v,
       CASE v.v WHEN 'a' THEN s.a WHEN 'b' THEN s.ab WHEN 'c' THEN s.ca END a,
       CASE v.v WHEN 'a' THEN s.ab WHEN 'b' THEN s.b WHEN 'c' THEN s.bc END b,
       CASE v.v WHEN 'a' THEN s.ca WHEN 'b' THEN s.bc WHEN 'c' THEN s.c END c
FROM v CROSS JOIN s
ORDER BY v.v;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=befaa95c83bc6fcd4bdcd635da9f6596).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be a simpler solution but I can't see it. This is what I came up with:

```
with
d (s, d, x, y) as (
  select 'a', 'b', a, b from t
  union all select 'a', 'c', a, c from t
  union all select 'b', 'c', b, c from t
  union all select 'a', 'a', a, a from t
  union all select 'b', 'b', c, c from t
  union all select 'c', 'c', c, c from t
),
r (s, d, cnt) as (
  select s, d, count(*)
  from d
  where x = 1 and y = 1
  group by s, d
)
select s, max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c
from (
  select s,
    sum(case when d = 'a' then cnt else 0 end) as a,
    sum(case when d = 'b' then cnt else 0 end) as b,
    sum(case when d = 'c' then cnt else 0 end) as c
  from r
  group by s
  union all 
  select d,
    sum(case when s = 'a' then cnt else 0 end) as a,
    sum(case when s = 'b' then cnt else 0 end) as b,
    sum(case when s = 'c' then cnt else 0 end) as c
  from r
  group by d
) x
group by s
```

Result:

```
 s  a  b  c 
 -- -- -- - 
 a  3  2  1 
 b  2  1  1 
 c  1  1  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2e0ef50041b73522071ecd702899611).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```
  Cols = CASE WHEN GROUPING(a) = 0 THEN 'a'
              WHEN GROUPING(b) = 0 THEN 'b'
              ELSE 'c' END,
  a = COUNT(NULLIF(a, 0)),
  b = COUNT(NULLIF(b, 0)),
  c = COUNT(NULLIF(c, 0))
FROM tab
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (a),
  (b),
  (c)
)
HAVING ISNULL(ISNULL(a, b), c) = 1
ORDER BY Cols;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac62f61c1b107f3663078f83b41f54b0)

This assumes that you have a `bit` column. Otherwise you should do `SUM(a)` etc.

---

- `GROUPING SETS` outputs a separate `GROUP BY` for each set of grouping columns, a bit like a `UNION ALL`.
- The `GROUPING` function tells you whether a column has been aggregated.
- `COUNT(NULLIF(someValue, 0))` only counts a value if it is not `0`.
- `HAVING` filters out cases when the grouping column is `0`.

Comment: It's not necessarily an invalid result. There is no missing information in the cross-tab, because it's effectively a mirror image (always symmetrical along the diagonal)

Comment: no rows in tab or all rows with 0 —> no result .. something is lost